# Javascript - Changing Object data source

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

I wanted to make a same header and footer but with different content pages. My current course only covers HTML, JS, CSS, and JQuery.

Here is my current body, simplified:

```
<div id="header">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="contentOne()">Content One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="contentTwo()">Content Two</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="contents">
   <object id="change" data="contentOne.html" type="text/html" height="100%" width="100%">
   </object>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   <p>The footer</p>
</div>
```

Inside the head are something like this:

```
<head>
   <script>
      function contentOne(){
         document.getElementById("change").data = "contentOne.html";
      }

      function contentTwo(){
         document.getElementById("change").data = "contentTwo.html";
      }
   </script>
</head>
```

The problem is, that I can't get the content to change. It looks like it would work but, for example, clicking on `ContentTwo`, doesn't load `contentTwo`. The page remains the same.

Comment: @Teemu I couldn't get the content to change. It looks like it would work but, for example, clicking on ContentTwo, doesn't load contentTwo. The page remains the same

Answer (score 3):

You shall use `setAttribute` for native JS or `.prop` for jquery:

```
 function contentOne(){
        // native
        var element =  document.getElementById("change");
        element.setAttribute("data", "contentOne.html");

        // jquery
        $("#change").prop("data","contentOne.html");
      }
```

Make sure you properly close the attribute values, `height="100% width="100%>` is wrong, also the `object` element shall be closed with `</object>` :

```
 <object id="change" data="contentOne.html"  
     type="text/html" height="100%" width="100%"></object>
```

Comment: The `data` attribute is exposed as the `data` property on `object` elements.  [Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-object-element.html).

Comment: Tested it using the setAttribute and holy crap it worked! I wonder why it didn't work previously? Can't I just change it directly with .data = "contentOne.html"

Comment: @OrewaAfif What browser are you using?  As per my link above, the specification mandates that setting the `data` property should be identical to setting the `data` attribute.  The browser you're using might be buggy and need a bug report filing.